# Error Post Method with Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following error when trying to post a partial view form on my page:

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

The error is related to the line below within the main view

The Main View is:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
@Html.ActionLink("Create a Club", "SelectClubType", "Club")

</div>

<div>
@Html.Action("SelectClubType", "Club")
</div>

<div class="row">
<p>something here</p>
</div>
```

The Partial View is:

```
@model GRCWebApp.ViewModels.SelectClubTypeViewModel

@{
Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <h3>Create a new Club - Select the type</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedClubTypeId, new   SelectList(Model.ClubTypes, "ClubTypeId", "ClubTypeName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The Post Method:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SelectClubType(SelectClubTypeViewModel model)
    {
        int id = model.SelectedClubTypeId;
        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = id });
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487729/why-is-asp-net-throwing-so-many-exceptions

Comment: Can you show the rest of the main view?

Comment: edited to show the full main view